# How to add blank space validation in template driven form in angular

Tags: angular

Here form code available. This form type is template driven form
In this form SUBSCRIPTION_ID input available. I need add validation like only blank space not allowed.

```
<form name="ResgisterData" #resgisterData = "ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="signUp(resgisterData.value)" novalidate>
<label>SUBSCRIPTION_ID</label>
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{ 'alert-danger' : subscriptionId.touched && subscriptionId?.errors?.required }" role="textbox" name="Guid" #subscriptionId="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="attendeLabDetails.SubscriptionGuid" autocomplete="off"  class="form-control" required />
<button role="button" class="btn btn-primary blue" [disabled]="resgisterData.invalid">Register </button>
</form>
```

Comment: use `pattern` attribute with regex value of `/^\S*$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Steps

Refer to [angular docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator):

You could create a validator directive.

1. Use `ng generate` to generate a new directive called **WhiteSpaceValidator**
2. After you've done this implement the validator interface in your directive: `Validator`
3. Add the code to check for whitespaces
4. Add directive to your input

#### Validator File

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[whiteSpaceValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: WhiteSpaceValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
class WhiteSpaceValidatorDirectiveimplements Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
    /*
    Your validation code here.
    */
    return {'whiteSpace': true};

  }
}
```

Your `subscriptionId?.errors` will then have the property `'whiteSpace': true`

Comment: Any other solution available?

Comment: Sure - there are quite a number of options, but I would recommend the above for angular.

You could do some other operations on `blur`/`keyup` that could perhaps automatically remove spaces - depends on what you want to achieve.